# How to get specific Object to the angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript

I use angular for front end while node.js use for backend with mongodb. i want to get specific Customer object by given _id. I created node.js method and able to send request using postman and able to get result. but i unable to send output to front end. Can you give a solution to output the result in form or paragraph.

Node.js Code:

```js
    const getCustomer = (req, resp) => {
    let {id} = req.params;
    CustomerSchema.findById(id).then(result =>{
        resp.status(200).json(result);
      }).catch(error =>{
        resp.status(500).json(result);
      })   
   };
```

angular code:

```js
    private setCustomerToForm() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      if (!id){
        return;
      }
       this.customerService.getCustomer(id).subscribe(customer => {
       this.customer = customer;
       console.log(this.customer)
      },error => this.onWarning('Error'));


    });
  }
```

Customer DTO contains CustomerName, CustomerNic
Thank You

Comment: add the definition of `this.customerService.getCustomer(id)`

Comment: I added noh..see my code

Comment: No, you didn't add your service file that contains the `getCustomer`'s definition.

Comment: constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private customerService: CustomerService,
    private router: Router,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {
    this.loadAll();
  }

Comment: Please add the code that is inside your service.

Comment: public getCustomer(id: string): Observable<CustomerDTO> {
    return this.http.get<CustomerDTO>(this.myUrl + 'customerRoute/getCustomer/: id', {headers: {id}});
  }
}

Comment: the URL here should be like ``${this.myUrl}customerRoute/getCustomer/${id}``. You're not using the id parameter in your url

Answer (score 0):

U better console.log({data}) to see what u got from backend first.
Try this:

```
this.customerService.getCustomer(id).subscribe(data => {
   console.log({data});
   const { customer } = data;
   this.customer = customer;
   console.log(this.customer);
},error => this.onWarning('Error'));
```